# HABTM Query help

Tags: mysql, sql, has-and-belongs-to-many, sql-match-all

I have a HABTM relationship between 'articles' and 'tags'

**Problem:** I'm only looking for articles with BOTH the tag 'sports' and 'outdoors' but not articles with only one of these tags.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT article.id, article.name FROM articles
inner JOIN tags ON (tags.name IN ('outdoors', 'sports')
inner JOIN articles_tags ON articles_tags.article_id = article.id AND articles_tags.tag_id = tags.id
```

...but it gets me articles that are in only sports, only outdoors AND both sports + outdoors

**Question** what is the right query to use? (I'm using MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common solutions.

- The first solution uses `GROUP BY` to count the tags per article that match 'outdoors' or 'sports' and then returns only the groups that have both tags.

  ```
  SELECT a.id, a.name
  FROM articles AS a
  INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at ON (a.id = at.article_id)
  INNER JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = at.tag_id)
  WHERE t.name IN ('outdoors', 'sports')
  GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = 2;
  ```

  This solution appears more readable to some people, and adding values is more straightforward.  But `GROUP BY` queries in MySQL tend to incur a temporary table which harms performance.
- The other solution uses a `JOIN` per distinct tag.  By using inner joins, the query naturally restricts to articles that match all the tags you specify.

  ```
  SELECT a.id, a.name
  FROM articles AS a
  INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at1 ON (a.id = at1.article_id)
  INNER JOIN tags AS t1 ON (t1.id = at1.tag_id AND t1.name = 'outdoors')
  INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at2 ON (a.id = at2.article_id)
  INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON (t2.id = at2.article_id AND t2.name = 'sports');
  ```

  Assuming `tags.name` and `articles_tags.(article_id,tag_id)` both have `UNIQUE` constraints, you shouldn't need a `DISTINCT` query modifier.

  This type of query tends to optimize better on MySQL than the `GROUP BY` solution, assuming you have defined appropriate indexes.

---

Re your followup question in the comment, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.tag) AS all_tags
FROM articles AS a
INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at1 ON (a.id = at1.article_id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t1 ON (t1.id = at1.tag_id AND t1.name = 'outdoors')
INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at2 ON (a.id = at2.article_id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON (t2.id = at2.article_id AND t2.name = 'sports');
INNER JOIN articles_tags AS at3 ON (a.id = at3.article_id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t3 ON (t3.id = at3.article_id);
GROUP BY a.id;
```

This still only finds articles that have both tags 'outdoors' and 'sports', but then it further joins these articles to *all* its tags.

This will return multiple rows per article (one for each tag) so we then use `GROUP BY` to reduce down to a single row per article again.  [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) returns a comma-separated list of the values in the respective group.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... Also, is it possible within this query to return all the tags associated with the matching articles?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a1.id, a1.name FROM articles a1
    JOIN tags t1 ON t1.name ='outdoors'
    JOIN articles_tags at1 ON at1.article_id = a1.id AND at1.tag_id = t1.id
    JOIN tags t2 ON t2.name = 'sports'
    JOIN articles_tags at2 ON at2.article_id = a1.id AND at2.tag_id = t2.id
```